# Got error : return an empty string to bool

Tags: swift

I want to test if the input string is "". If the input string is "", then return false.

```
 var x = ""
 func beginsWithVowel(x: String) -> Bool {
    if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "a" || x.characters[x.startIndex] == "A"{
        return true
    }else if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "e" || x.characters[x.startIndex] == "E"{
        return true
    }else if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "i" || x.characters[x.startIndex] == "I"{
        return true
    }else if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "o" || x.characters[x.startIndex] == "O"{
        return true
    }else if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "u" || x.characters[x.startIndex] == "U"{
        return true
    }else {
    return false
    }
}

beginsWithVowel(x: x)
```

But I got a error: fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String.
How can i fix it? Thank You.
P.S. cant use optional string and the problem wan't how to check empty string, but why it cant return bool in function.

Comment: I'd check first if x is empty (before checking if it's A, E, etc), so no method would be applied to an empty string ('.characters' seems to cast x to a Character, so it might be throwing an exception there).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the empty check first

```
func beginsWithVowel(x: String) -> Bool {
    if x.isEmpty { return false }
    if x.characters[x.startIndex] == "a" { ...
```

Slightly different approach using regular expression, it includes the empty check:

```
func beginsWithVowel(x: String) -> Bool {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[aeiou]", options: .caseInsensitive)
    return regex.firstMatch(in: x, range: NSMakeRange(0, x.utf16.count)) != nil
}
```

Comment: why make the empty check first can fix it?
is there any principle?

Comment: Because if it passes the test it's guaranteed that there is at least one character in the string. The error occurs if there is no character at `startIndex`. Btw: Retrieving the first character 10 times with this syntax is very inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use guard to make sure your string has the first character and you can use an array with your vowels and check if it contains the first character.

```
func beginsWithVowel(x: String) -> Bool {
    guard let first = x.characters.first else { return false }
    return ["a","e","i","o","u","A","E","I","O","U"].contains(first)
}
```

Comment: You can simplify that to `.contains(first)` since Swift will then infer the literal array to be `[Character]`.